# TBSelenium: Tor page closes immediately

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I'm trying to use Tor with selenium, which works through the use of tbselenium.

However, when loading an url or clicking a web element, the page immideately closes when finishing the action, instead of remaining open as would be the case when using selenium with chrome.

Any ideas to keep the page open?

```
import tbselenium.common as cm
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
from tbselenium.utils import launch_tbb_tor_with_stem

tbb_dir = "C:\\pathto\\Tor Browser\\"
tor_process = launch_tbb_tor_with_stem(tbb_path=tbb_dir)
for i in range(1):
with TorBrowserDriver(tbb_dir, tor_cfg=cm.USE_STEM) as driver:
    driver.load_url("http://hln.be",3,wait_for_page_body=True)
    #driver.get('https://google.be')


    try:
        policypage=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'members/join')]")
        policypage.click()
        usern=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'user_member_username')]")
        usern.send_keys('Tryout')
    except:
        print('different look')
```

Comment: use standard `driver = TorBrowserDriver(tbb_dir, tor_cfg=cm.USE_STEM)`. When you use `with` then (probably) it closes it automatically when it leave `with`.

Answer (score 1):

As Furas said, use the standard driver declaration.